# Decrypting the hashed windows passwords in SAM

Tags: windows

I realise passwords are hashed using LMHash and then encrypted using SYSKEY, is there any sort of implementation code (preferably in Java) for SYSKEY so that i can create rainbow tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sites I could link to are fishy and I''m not sure if they are safe, but you can google `syskey rainbow tables` and you'll find some information you need.

However, you should probably shouldn't unless you need this information for ethical reasons.